# Getting blog pagination to work on page set as front page

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, pagination

From what I understand, if the page is the front page (using front-page.php) you would use `get_query_var('page')` and for other pages you would use `get_query_var('paged')`. I have a condition for this and the pagination works to an extent. If I click on "Next" it shows the next set of records however on the home page the pagination itself doesn't change ie: on page 2, the number 2 isn't highlighted and the 'previous' button isn't present like on other pages.

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
}else {
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
}

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$all_posts = new WP_Query($args);


 <?php while ($all_posts->have_posts() ): $all_posts->the_post(); ?>
    display post title, date etc. here
 <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
 
<div class="pagination">
    <?php
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links(
    array(
        'prev_text' => __( 'Previous' ),
        'next_text' => __( 'Next' ),
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(
            1,
            get_query_var('paged')
        ),
        'total' => $all_posts->max_num_pages
    )
);
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that on the *static* front page, we use `get_query_var('page')` to get the current page number.

And actually, the issue in question ("*the number 2 isn't highlighted*") happened because you used `get_query_var('paged')` (note the `paged`) with the `current` arg for [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/), which means you're passing the wrong number.

```php
'current' => max(
    1,
    get_query_var('paged')
),
```

So all you need to do is replace that with `'current' => $paged,` and the problem will be gone.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks so much for that :)